# everyauth error: missing code in querystring

Tags: node.js, express, everyauth

I am using express with everyauth.
When I authenticate using facebook I got the exception:

```
Missing code in querystring. The url looks like /auth/facebook/callback?error_code=2102&error_message=User+is+not+a+test+user+owned+by+the+application
Error: Step getCode of `facebook` is promising: code ; however, the step returns nothing. Fix the step by returning the expected values OR by returning a Promise that promises said values.
```

What is the problem?